# What is that Russian bread appetizer called that is really puffed up and then you touch it and it decreases in volume and then you can dip it in a dip

Tags: russian-cuisine

What is that bread appetizer that is served in restaurants in Russia called that is really puffed up and then you touch it and it decreases in volume and then you can dip it in a dip and eat it, it used to be on instagram a lot.

For example here: https://www.instagram.com/aidabaran_restoran/

Comment: If it was on Instagram a lot, a photo would be very helpful.

Comment: Sounds like a popover of some sort

Comment: You're going to need a photo for people to answer this.

Comment: Voting to close; the OP doesn't seem to understand what SA is for.

Comment: I don't think the identification of a food item is off topic. Yes, a picture would be helpful.  Again, I'll say that the only result of down voting a question is to that it discourages new users.  If the question is off topic, it can be closed.  If it needs clarity, it can be edited.  If we already answered it, i can be identified as a dupe.  If the user is spamming the system, mods can remove them. Down voting questions does not help this forum. My campaign continues...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the name. It's called ["chebureki"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebureki), a form of turnover originating from the Crimean Peninsula.
[image: photo of a puffy half-moon pastry on a plate]
(Photo from [Wikipedia](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ayran%2B%C3%87ib%C3%B6rek.jpg#mw-jump-to-license))

Comment: Chebureki doesn't really fit the description. While it does puff up a bit during cooking, it doesn't "decrease in volume" when you touch it. It also wouldn't ordinarily be served with a dip.

Comment: @sneftel you can't see it from the current state of the question, but this is a self-answer. So this is indeed the food the OP meant, aven if they misremembered it's qualities while describing.

Comment: @rumtscho I know it's a self-answer. I think it's an incorrect one.

Comment: @Sneftel it appears to be the correct answer, even though the variation the OP is describing is not the same as the one in the Wikipedia photo. If you have an Instagram account, you can go to the link that was added to the question, and scroll down to the older pictures. You'll find a few clips showing exactly what the OP described, e.g. a video from 17. august where a blonde woman in a white corsage with shoulder straps eats it, and the restaurant itself titles it АйДаЧебурек, which is simply "cheburek" combined with the restaurant's name.

Comment: @rumtscho I was able to find a YouTube video https://youtube.com/watch?v=FOv92fF3f4M of nearly exactly this - it’s titled “Ayda Cheburek”

Comment: @Sneftel see the above comment (if you don’t have an Instagram account). Seems to be a particular variant of the dish

Comment: @fyrepenguin The restaurant in the original question is called "Ayda Baran" so it could be either a widespread variation but served at this place under their own brand name, like a "McRib", or something that this restaurant invented and is serving uniquely. I don't follow Instagram channels so I don't know which it is.

Comment: @Sneftel also it doesn't really "decrease in volume" on its own. The people in the instagram video actually had to press it down to squish it. The one in the question is rather large in size compared to the photo in the answer.